# How to initialize UniChar with too many bytes in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, unicode

[image]I am trying to initialize a UniChar variable, like:

```
var unicode: UniChar = 0x1F63E
```

"Integer literal '128701' overflows when stored into 'UniChar' (aka 'UInt16')"

But if I initialize with a shorter unicode value, like:

```
var unicode: UniChar = 0x2705
```

Everything is alright.

How do I do the first one?

Comment: You can't. `UniChar` can only hold values 0x0000 through 0xFFFF. Show why you want to use `UniChar` instead of `Character`.

Comment: ... or UnicodeScalar. – What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to programmatically write an emoji via `.keyboardSetUnicodeString`, which takes a UniChar value ... I'll add a screenshot

Comment: this is the function I am attempting to use: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgevent/1456028-keyboardsetunicodestring

Comment: You need to use unicode `"\u{1F6BD}"` or `Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(0x1F6BD))!)`

Comment: @LeoDabus if i do `var unicode: UniChar = "\u{1F6BD}"` i get this error: "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to specified type 'UniChar' (aka 'UInt16')"

Comment: Please post code as text, not a picture. Pictures can't be referenced or searched and they are harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function expects (the pointer to) an array of `UniChar` aka `UInt16`,
containing the UTF-16 representation of the string.
As @rmaddy said, `UniChar` can hold only values up to 0xFFFF.
Larger Unicode scalars need to be represented as “surrogate pairs”.

The `.utf16` view of a string provides the UTF-16 representation:

```
let c = "\u{1F63E}" // Or: let c = ""
let utf16Chars = Array(c.utf16)
event.keyboardSetUnicodeString(stringLength: utf16Chars.count, unicodeString: utf16Chars)
```